# ¿Cómo evito que en la salida el cicle me de "n" veces la misma impresión?

Tags: python, json

Ok, soy nuevo en programación con Python y estoy tomando un curso de ello, y como segunda asignación de actividades me dieron lo siguiente:

Usando un archivo JSON que contiene esto:

```
{ "data":
  [
    {
      "d_ciudad":"Ciudad de México",
      "c_mnpio":"010",
      "d_cp":"01001",
      "c_cp":"",
      "d_estado":"Ciudad de México",
      "c_estado":"09",
      "d_asenta":"San Ángel",
      "d_tipo_asenta":"Colonia",
      "d_nmpio":"Álvaro Obregón",
      "c_oficina":"01001",
      "id_asenta_cpcons":"0001",
      "c_tipo_asenta":"09",
      "d_codigo":"01000",
      "c_cve_ciudad":"01",
      "d_zona":"Urbano"
    },
    {
      "d_ciudad":"Ciudad de México",
      "c_mnpio":"010",
      "d_cp":"01001",
      "c_cp":"",
      "d_estado":"Ciudad de México",
      "c_estado":"09",
      "d_asenta":"Los Alpes",
      "d_tipo_asenta":"Colonia",
      "d_nmpio":"Álvaro Obregón",
      "c_oficina":"01001",
      "id_asenta_cpcons":"0005",
      "c_tipo_asenta":"09",
      "d_codigo":"01010",
      "c_cve_ciudad":"01",
      "d_zona":"Urbano"
    },
    {
      "d_ciudad":"Ciudad de México",
      "c_mnpio":"010",
      "d_cp":"01001",
      "c_cp":"",
      "d_estado":"Ciudad de México",
      "c_estado":"09",
      "d_asenta":"Axotla",
      "d_tipo_asenta":"Pueblo",
      "d_nmpio":"Álvaro Obregón",
      "c_oficina":"01001",
      "id_asenta_cpcons":"0009",
      "c_tipo_asenta":"28",
      "d_codigo":"01030",
      "c_cve_ciudad":"01",
      "d_zona":"Urbano"
    },
    {
      "d_ciudad":"Ciudad de México",
      "c_mnpio":"010",
      "d_cp":"01001","c_cp":"",
      "d_estado":"Ciudad de México",
      "c_estado":"09",
      "d_asenta":"Florida",
      "d_tipo_asenta":"Colonia",
      "d_nmpio":"Álvaro Obregón",
      "c_oficina":"01001",
      "id_asenta_cpcons":"0010",
      "c_tipo_asenta":"09",
      "d_codigo":"01030",
      "c_cve_ciudad":"01",
      "d_zona":"Urbano"
    },
    {
      "d_ciudad":"Ciudad de México",
      "c_mnpio":"010",
      "d_cp":"01001",
      "c_cp":"",
      "d_estado":"Ciudad de México",
      "c_estado":"09",
      "d_asenta":"Campestre",
      "d_tipo_asenta":"Colonia",
      "d_nmpio":"Álvaro Obregón",
      "c_oficina":"01001",
      "id_asenta_cpcons":"0012",
      "c_tipo_asenta":"09",
      "d_codigo":"01040",
      "c_cve_ciudad":"01",
      "d_zona":"Urbano"
    }
  ]
}
```

Usando este JSON debo hacer tres acciones:

1. Leer un Código Postal desde teclado
2. Buscar en los datos del diccionario el Código Postal leído y desplegar a que Estado y Municipio pertenece
3. En caso de NO haber coincidencia desplegar un mensaje de: "Código Postal NO encontrado"

Los primeros dos objetivos de la actividad creo que los tengo resueltos, el problema viene al realizas las impresiones. El siguiente es el código que tengo hasta el momento:

```
# cargar modulo json
import json

# leer archivo JSON
# cambiar el nombre del archivo de codigosPostales a codigos_postales para utilizar archivo completo
with open('codigosPostales.json', 'r' , encoding="utf8") as file:
  datos = json.load(file)

# ingresar CP a buscar en archivo json
codPost = input("\n" + "¿Qué código postal desea buscar? ")

# analizar el archivo para buscar los llaves y los valores
for i in datos['data']:
  # buscar el valor especificado
  if codPost == i['d_codigo']:
    # imprimir los valores de municipio y estado correspondientes al CP buscado
    print("\n" + "El código postal " + codPost + " pertenece al municipio de" + i['d_nmpio'] + ", de" + i['d_estado'] + "\n")
  else:
    print("Código postal NO encontrado.")
```

Y esta es la salida cuando el código postal sí se encuentra en el JSON:

```
Código postal NO encontrado.
El código postal 01010 pertenece al municipio deÁlvaro Obregón, deCiudad de México
Código postal NO encontrado.
Código postal NO encontrado.
Código postal NO encontrado.
```

Y esta la salida cuando el código postal no se encuentra en el JSON:

```
Código postal NO encontrado.
Código postal NO encontrado.
Código postal NO encontrado.
Código postal NO encontrado.
Código postal NO encontrado.
```

Entiendo que me da una línea de salida por cada colección que hay en el JSON, cinco en este caso. La salida no da "ningún" problema hasta antes de agregar el else, pues sin este, las salidas son las siguientes:
En caso de encontrar el código postal...

```
El código postal 01010 pertenece al municipio deÁlvaro Obregón, deCiudad de México
```

En caso de no encontrar el código posta:

La salida vacía para el caso de no encontrar, entiendo que es porque sale del ciclo por la condición que no se cumple.

Puestos en contexto me gustaría que me guiaran para poder cumplir con los objetivos de la actividad. De manera que pueda obtener una sola salida si el código es encontrado y una sola si no.
Debo mencionar que he intentado resolverlo usando funciones, y ciclo while, pero creo que me desvié del objetivo al hacerlo y esta fue la manera más sencilla que encontré, pero creo que sigo perdido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que para cada iteración, sí o sí se va a ejecutar una de estas dos acciones **por la propia estructura de la sentencia if - else:**

```
if codPost == i['d_codigo']:
    # imprimir los valores de municipio y estado correspondientes al CP buscado
    print("\n" + "El código postal " + codPost + " pertenece al municipio de" + i['d_nmpio'] + ", de" + i['d_estado'] + "\n")
  else:
    print("Código postal NO encontrado.")
```

Si quieres mejorar el código, te recomiendo que luego de entrar al `if` de `codPost == i['d_codigo']` mandes un `break`, eso hará terminar la ejecución del bucle  `for`.

```
if codPost == i['d_codigo']:
    # imprimir los valores de municipio y estado correspondientes al CP buscado
    print("\n" + "El código postal " + codPost + " pertenece al municipio de" + i['d_nmpio'] + ", de" + i['d_estado'] + "\n")
    break
```

Además, retirar la sentencia `else` y reemplazar por:

```
print("Código postal NO encontrado.")
```

De esta manera, si luego de evaluar todas las posibilidades, la ejecución nunca entró a la sentencia  `if` de `codPost == i['d_codigo']`, es porque el código no existe, y en ese caso recién debes imprimir el mensaje de "no encontrado". Debes notar que si se llega a encontrar el código postal, entonces el bucle termina ahí y no se imprimirá el mensaje de "no encontrado".

El codigo final quedaría así :

```
# cargar modulo json
import json

# leer archivo JSON
# cambiar el nombre del archivo de codigosPostales a codigos_postales para utilizar archivo completo
with open('codigosPostales.json', 'r' , encoding="utf8") as file:
  datos = json.load(file)

# ingresar CP a buscar en archivo json
codPost = input("\n" + "¿Qué código postal desea buscar? ")

# analizar el archivo para buscar los llaves y los valores
state = False
for i in datos['data']:
  # buscar el valor especificado
  if codPost == i['d_codigo']:
    # imprimir los valores de municipio y estado correspondientes al CP buscado
    state = True
    break
if state: 
    print("\n" + "El código postal " + codPost + " pertenece al municipio de" + i['d_nmpio'] + ", de" + i['d_estado'] + "\n")
else:
    print("Código postal NO encontrado.")
```

Comment: justo estaba comentando sobre tu segunda sugerencia, cuando realizaste la nueva, la cual tampoco me da la salida. Esta nueva, es la llamada bandera?

Comment: Muchas gracias, Luis Felipe, ha estado excelente, me has salvado la vida.